# Как установить sсss в sublime text

Tags: css, scss, sublime-text-3

Чтобы компилировалось из scss в css. Ничего не нашёл в интернете, на mail ответах тоже.

Comment: редактор тут не причем. вместо него можно и блокнотом пользоваться. и волшебных плагинов, которые конвертируют файлы, вы к редакторам не найдете. вам нужен таск раннер, который запускается отдельно из командной строки. подробнее тут: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7yYD3qVchw&t=0s

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно убедится что утилита sass установлена глобально
для этого можно выполнить `npm list -g | grep sass`

Если ничего не найдено то можно установить `npm install sass -g` флаг `-g` отвечает за глобальную установку т.е. `sass` будет доступна из любой папки.

Далее в Sublime нужно создать `Build System` выбрав `Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...`

после чего вставить это содержимое:

```
{
    "cmd": ["SASS_PATH", "$file", "$file_path/$file_name.css"],
    "selector": "source.sass",
    "path" : "NODE_PATH"
}
```

`cmd` вызывает комманду с двумя аргументами, первый текущий файл, второй файл с разширением css, если нужны дополнительные опции их можно посмотреть набрав в консоли `sass` и нажав ввод.

`SASS_PATH` и `NODE_PATH` нужно заменить соответствующими путями.
Найти эти пути в Linux можно коммандой `which sass` и `which node` соответсвенно и сохранить файл под именем `sass.sublime-build`

После чего нужно открыть сохраненный файл стилей, либо набрать новый и сохранить (главное чтобы файл имел расширение `.sass`).

Далее убедится что в качестве `Build System` выбрана `sass`

и нажать `Control + B` (Linux / Windows) или `Command + B (OS X)`